# Number of operations on Cbits and Qbits

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

What is the maximum number of operations that can be defined on Cbits (like mechanical switches) and Qbits (like quantum states)? If they are different how will the ratio change if we limit ourselves to Reversible circuits?

Edit: By operation I mean that a n-bit state remains an n-bit state

Comment: Might use Linear Algebra, as state remains same. Search matrices with determinant non-0.

Answer (score 0):

There are $2^{n2^n}$ binary gates (or rather, equivalent circuits doing the same transformation) that map $n$ input binary bits to $n$ arbitrary output bits. Think of each of the $2^n$ possible inputs as one row where there are $n$ columns for the output bits; there are $2^{n2^n}$ possible binary allocations of this $2^n\times n$ matrix.

A reversible gate performs a permutation of each possible input ($2^n$ of them) to each possible output, so they can be represented as $2^n \times 2^n$ permutation matrices, of which there are $(2^n)!$.

In principle you can have infinite quantum gates. A quantum gate which acts on $n$ qubits is represented by a $2^n \times 2^n$ unitary matrix, and the values can be continuously changed as long as unitarity is preserved. If you demand that the gate will map each basis state to another basis state, then you end up with the reversible gates above.